# Correct way to use enableMainFragmentScaling and setExpand methods?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

anyone familiar with Android TV / Leanback library could provide information on how to correctly use the methods enableMainFragmentScaling from BrowseSupportFragment and setExpand from RowsSupportFragment?

Answer (score 0):

enableMainFragmentScaling visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/leanback/app/BrowseSupportFragment)

```
open fun enableMainFragmentScaling(enable: Boolean): Unit
```

Enables scaling of main fragment when headers are present. For the page/row fragment, scaling is enabled only when both this method and MainFragmentAdapter#isScalingEnabled() are enabled.

Parameters
enable  Boolean: true to enable row scaling

setExpand visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/RowsSupportFragment#setexpand)

```
void setExpand (boolean expand)
```

Set the visibility of titles/hovercard of browse rows.

Parameters
expand  boolean

-

I'm afraid there is little documentation on these methods and there use really depends on the situation. If you are looking to do something specific its probably a better idea to post your code rather than ask people to fully explain a whole method. Sorry.